# Finding space in byte[]

Tags: java, integer, byte

I would like to check if my byte has space in it.

I tried to write and

this is my V

```
«h KD4@o2298
```

and:

```
byte[] V;
V=readBytesFromFile("Y:\\IV.txt");

if(V !=" "){
}
```

but it's not working

It's possible?

Comment: That's not a `byte` but an array of `byte`. `byte` itself has like any primitive type a fixed size (always 8-bit), so i'm not sure what you want to check for "8 characters". Do you want to check if the array has a length of 8?

Comment: in the code you have a byte arr V. are you checking for the arr length? you can do V.length

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes. I want to find the length. or if there is any space between. one of this.

Comment: @Aru12 I'm afraid you lost me again with the "space between" and i have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @moficodes ``` if(V.length != ){
   
   } ```  illegal start of expression.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS spacebar - I don't know how to say it properly.

Comment: @Aru12 I understand what you are saying but it makes absolutely no sense. How would an array of byte contain a "spacebar"? I honestly think you should take a step back and try to reformulate your question and describe what exactly this byte array represents and what you are trying to do in a lot more detail.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS look now. I edited it.

Comment: V is an Array. It will never be equal to a string.

Comment: Also byte is a 8 bit value. it can not have a space in it.

Comment: @moficodes original file is «h KD4@o - without these numbers. between h and K is space. and I wanna write if, which tells me "Yes, there is space"

Comment: You mean like `V.toString().contains(" ")`?

Comment: @Marvin when I convert it to String, it happens strange, because it creates like hidden space when I click → I must click there twice to go to the next char